# How do I hook an afterFind type callback/event in Waterline?

Tags: sails.js, waterline

I would like to hook an event after an object is retrieved from the database. This event should be fired regardless if the object is retrieved from `.find()` or via a `.populate()` call. I would think it should be similar to the other [lifecycle callbacks](https://github.com/balderdashy/waterline#lifecycle-callbacks) like `afterCreate` or `afterUpdate`, etc.

Is this possible to do with Waterline and if so, how can it be accomplished?

> To give an idea of what I'm trying to accomplish: I'm using Mongo to
>   store my data. There is the potential that the model schema has
>   changed since the record was last saved. I'd like to "upgrade" the
>   record retrieved from the database to the latest version using a
>   function defined on the model itself. I would like this process to
>   happen as transparently as possible after a query returns (ie. Not
>   have to explicitly call the function in each query callback function).

Comment: This feature is not implemented yet. You can vote for it here: https://github.com/balderdashy/waterline/issues/923